# Disable customer attribute for editing in magento admin form for specific Roles Resources

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.4

How could we disable some input field for customer in admin form.For custom specific Roles Resources.

Answer (score 1):

For achieving this things i have used the following steps.As we know basic structure of creating module step. so here i am just putting required files.

**app/code/[Vendor_Name]/[Module_Name]/etc/acl.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Magento_Customer::customer">
                    <resource id="Magento_Customer::manage">
                        <resource id="[Vendor_Name]_[Module_Name]::allow_editable_some_fields" title="Allow editable some fields" translate="title" sortOrder="110" />
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

**app/code/[Vendor_Name]/[Module_Name]/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!--
    /**
     * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    -->
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="customer">
        <field name="[custom_attribute_field_name]" formElement="input" class="[Vendor_Name]/[Module_Name]\Ui\Component\Form\Field\DisableSomeField">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">customer</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">400</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**app/code/[Vendor_Name]/[Module_Name]/Ui/Component/Form/Field/DisableSomeField.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace [Vendor_Name]\[Module_Name]\Ui\Component\Form\Field;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentInterface;
use Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface;

/**
 * Process setting to set input field Disable according to roles resources
 *
 * Class [Vendor_Name]\[Module_Name]\Ui\Component\Form\Field\DisableSomeField
 */
class DisableSomeField extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field
{
    /**
     * @var AuthorizationInterface
     */
    private $authorization;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param AuthorizationInterface $authorization
     * @param UiComponentInterface[] $components
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        AuthorizationInterface $authorization,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->authorization = $authorization;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare component configuration
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function prepare()
    {
        parent::prepare();
        
        $isAllowed = $this->authorization->isAllowed('[Vendor_Name]_[Module_Name]::allow_editable_some_fields');
        if (!$isAllowed) {
            $currentConfig = $this->getData('config');
            $currentConfig['disabled'] = true;
            $this->setData('config', $currentConfig);
        }
    }
}
```

Disabling Magento default functionality group dropdown not editable in mass action and grid listing.Here is the code to achieve it.

Create File on the below location :

**app/code/[Vendor]/[Module_Name]/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <massaction name="listing_massaction" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions" class="[Vendor]\[Module_Name]\Ui\Component\MassAction\Group\DisableGroup">
            <action name="assign_to_group">
                <settings>
                    <type>assign_to_group</type>
                    <label translate="true">Assign a Customer Group</label>
                    <actions class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\MassAction\Group\Options"/>
                </settings>
            </action>
        </massaction>
    </listingToolbar>
    <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\[Module_Name]\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <column name="group_id" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select" sortOrder="50" class="[Vendor]\[Module_Name]\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\DisableGroup">
            <settings>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>select</editorType>
                </editor>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Group</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

**app/code/[Vendor]/[Module_Name]/Ui/Component/MassAction/Group/DisableGroup.php**

```
<?php
    
    namespace [Vendor]\[Module_Name]\Ui\Component\MassAction\Group;
    
    use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface;
    
    /**
     * Process setting to set input field Disable according to roles resources
     *
     * Class \[Vendor]\[Module_Name]\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\DisableGroup
     */
    class DisableGroup extends \Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction
    {
    
        /**
         * @var AuthorizationInterface
         */
        private $authorization;
    
        /**
         * Constructor
         *
         * @param ContextInterface                      $context
         * @param AuthorizationInterface                $authorization
         * @param UiComponentInterface[]                $components
         * @param array                                 $data
         */
        public function __construct(
            ContextInterface $context,
            AuthorizationInterface $authorization,
            array $components,
            array $data
        ) {
            $this->authorization = $authorization;
            parent::__construct($context, $components, $data);
        }
    
        /**
         * Prepare component configuration
         *
         * @return void
         * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
         */
        public function prepare()
        {
            parent::prepare();
            if (!$this->authorization->isAllowed('[Vendor_Name]_[Module_Name]::allow_editable_some_fields')) {
                $config = $this->getConfiguration();
                $notAllowedActions = ['assign_to_group'];
                $allowedActions = [];
                foreach ($config['actions'] as $action) {
                    if (!in_array($action['type'], $notAllowedActions)) {
                        $action['actionDisable'] = true;
                        $allowedActions[] = $action;
                    }
                }
                $config['actions'] = $allowedActions;
                $this->setData('config', (array)$config);
            }
        }
    }
```

Disable group select in customer grid :

**app/code/[Vendor]/[Module_Name]/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/DisableGroup.php**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace [Vendor]\[Module_Name]\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface;

/**
 * Process setting to set input field Disable according to roles resources
 *
 * Class \[Vendor]\[Module_Name]\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\DisableGroup
 */
class DisableGroup extends Column
{
    /**
     * @var AuthorizationInterface
     */
    private $authorization;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param AuthorizationInterface $authorization
     * @param UiComponentInterface[] $components
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        AuthorizationInterface $authorization,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->authorization = $authorization;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare component configuration
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function prepare()
    {
        parent::prepare();

        if (!$this->authorization->isAllowed('[Vendor_Name]_[Module_Name]::allow_editable_some_fields')) {
            $currentConfig = $this->getData('config');
            if (isset($currentConfig['editor']['editorType'])) {
                $currentConfig['editor']['editorType'] = false;
                $this->setData('config', $currentConfig);
            }
        }
    }
}
```