# Disable fields in ui_component by user role

Tags: uicomponent, magento2.4.5, user-roles

We are using the WeltPixel Peal theme. Ultimately, I'd like to prevent specific User Roles from having access to the Custom CSS/JS fields that WeltPixel adds.

[image: WeltPixel Custom CSS fields]

These are the file paths where these fields are getting set currently:

/app/code/WeltPixel/DesignElements/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml
/app/code/WeltPixel/DesignElements/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_block_form.xml
/app/code/WeltPixel/DesignElements/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_page_form.xml

I think I can do this by moving them out of its current fieldset and into its own fieldset and then create an ACL for the new fieldset.

Would I create a new module to do this? Or is there another way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I was able to disable these Custom CSS/JS fields for specific User Roles.

I created a new module that referenced the WeltPixel module where these fields come from.

/app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="0.0.1.001">
        <sequence>
            <module name="WeltPixel_DesignElementst"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

I added the necessary checkboxes to the Categories, CMS Page and CMS Block for the User Roles.

/app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/acl.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
<acl>
    <resources>
        <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
            <resource id="Magento_Catalog::catalog">
                <resource id="Magento_Catalog::catalog_inventory">
                    <resource id="Magento_Catalog::categories">
                        <resource id="Vendor_Module::allow_category_css_edits"
                                  title="WeltPixel CSS Options" sortOrder="20"/>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::content">
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::content_elements">
                    <resource id="Magento_Cms::page">
                        <resource id="Magento_Cms::save">
                            <resource id="Vendor_Module::allow_cms_css_edits"
                                      title="WeltPixel CSS Options" sortOrder="20"/>
                        </resource>
                    </resource>
                    <resource id="Magento_Cms::block">
                        <resource id="Vendor_Module::allow_block_css_edits"
                                  title="WeltPixel CSS Options" sortOrder="20"/>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</acl>
</config>
```

[image: CMS Options]
[image: Category Option]

With the help of this post, [Disable customer attribute for editing in magento admin form for specific Roles Resources](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/347259/disable-customer-attribute-for-editing-in-magento-admin-form-for-specific-roles), I was then able to disable each of the Custom CSS/JS fields that WeltPixel adds.

For each of the form.xml files listed below, I duplicated the file in my module, and copied the fields into a new fieldset and then hid the original fields in their fieldsets.

/app/code/WeltPixel/DesignElements/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml /app/code/WeltPixel/DesignElements/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_block_form.xml /app/code/WeltPixel/DesignElements/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_page_form.xml

This code is for the category_form.xml file.

/src/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<fieldset name="weltpixel_options">
    <field name="css_global">
        <settings>
            <visible>false</visible>
        </settings>
    </field>
    <field name="css_phone_small">
        <settings>
            <visible>false</visible>
        </settings>
    </field>
    <field name="css_phone">
        <settings>
            <visible>false</visible>
        </settings>
    </field>
    <field name="css_tablet_small">
        <settings>
            <visible>false</visible>
        </settings>
    </field>
    <field name="css_tablet">
        <settings>
            <visible>false</visible>
        </settings>
    </field>
    <field name="css_desktop">
        <settings>
            <visible>false</visible>
        </settings>
    </field>
    <field name="css_desktop_large">
        <settings>
            <visible>false</visible>
        </settings>
    </field>
    <field name="custom_js">
        <settings>
            <visible>false</visible>
        </settings>
    </field>
</fieldset>
<fieldset name="weltpixel_cat_css_options">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">WeltPixel CSS Options</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">16</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <field name="css_global" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Form\Field\DisableCategoryCssFields">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">110</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">varchar</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Global CSS</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
    <field name="css_phone_small" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Form\Field\DisableCategoryCssFields">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">115</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">varchar</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom CSS for XXS screen size</item>
                <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Configure breakpoints in WeltPixel > Frontend Options > Breakpoints</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>

    <field name="css_phone" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Form\Field\DisableCategoryCssFields">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">120</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">varchar</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom CSS for XS screen size</item>
                <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Configure breakpoints in WeltPixel > Frontend Options > Breakpoints</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>

    <field name="css_tablet_small" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Form\Field\DisableCategoryCssFields">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">125</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">varchar</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom CSS for S screen size</item>
                <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Configure breakpoints in WeltPixel > Frontend Options > Breakpoints</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>

    <field name="css_tablet" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Form\Field\DisableCategoryCssFields">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">130</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">varchar</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom CSS for M screen size</item>
                <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Configure breakpoints in WeltPixel > Frontend Options > Breakpoints</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>

    <field name="css_desktop" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Form\Field\DisableCategoryCssFields">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">140</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">varchar</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom CSS for L screen size</item>
                <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Configure breakpoints in WeltPixel > Frontend Options > Breakpoints</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>

    <field name="css_desktop_large" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Form\Field\DisableCategoryCssFields">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">150</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">varchar</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom CSS for XL screen size</item>
                <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Configure breakpoints in WeltPixel > Frontend Options > Breakpoints</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>

    <field name="custom_js" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Form\Field\DisableCategoryCssFields">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">160</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">varchar</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Js</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>

</fieldset>
```

For cms_block_form.xml, the class on each of the fields is set to:
class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Form\Field\DisableBlockCssFields"

For cms_page_form.xml, the class on each of the fields is set to: class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Form\Field\DisableCmsCssFields"

For each of the classes, I created a similar file. This one is for the fields on the category screen.

/src/app/code/Vendor/Module/Ui/Component/Form/Field/DisableCategoryCssFields.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Form\Field;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentInterface;
use Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface;

/**
 * Process setting to set input field Disable according to roles resources
 *
 * Class Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Form\Field\DisableCategoryCssFields
 */
class DisableCategoryCssFields extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field
{
/**
 * @var AuthorizationInterface
 */
private $authorization;

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param ContextInterface $context
 * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
 * @param AuthorizationInterface $authorization
 * @param UiComponentInterface[] $components
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    ContextInterface $context,
    UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
    AuthorizationInterface $authorization,
    array $components = [],
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->authorization = $authorization;
    parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
}

/**
 * Prepare component configuration
 *
 * @return void
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
 */
public function prepare()
{
    parent::prepare();

    $isAllowed = $this->authorization->isAllowed('Vendor_Module::allow_category_css_edits');
    if (!$isAllowed) {
        $currentConfig = $this->getData('config');
        $currentConfig['disabled'] = true;
        $this->setData('config', $currentConfig);
    }
}
}
```

The "isAllowed" is different for the CMS Page and CMS Blocks. It is also referenced as the resource ID in the acl.xml filed.

For DisableCmsCssFields.php it is: Vendor_Module::allow_cms_css_edits

For DisableBlockCssFields.php it is: Vendor_Module::allow_block_css_edits

That should be it.

[image: Category Form - CSS Fields Disabled]